# Excel vba - column selection error

Tags: vba, excel

I need to `autofit` first two columns from `Sheetx`, but I want to be able to start **MACRO** from any other sheet so I'm using With-method.
How to avoid using Select in this case?

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetx")

With ws

    .Columns("A:B").Select

    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End with
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetx")

With ws
    .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
End with
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) might help you aswell.

Comment: Nice Answer: Note: The statment `EntireColumn` is not needed her. Because he selects allready the hole Column. This statment is only needed when he Would Select `Range("A1:B1")` then he would ned the `EntireColumn` Statment. 
Here it does not matter, however, if you use it in a big loop, it causes an unnecessary lookup every time.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetx")

With ws
    .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
End with
```